# Why does calling sbt.IO.download fail with type mismatch (required: sbt.internals.DslEntry)?

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to download a file with SBT, so I have written a small sbt file with this code in:

```
    import sbt._
    import java.net.URL
    import java.io.File

    lazy val text_url = new URL("http://www.example.com/text.txt")
    lazy val to_file = new File("text.txt")
    sbt.IO.download(text_url, to_file)
```

I have followed the API doc, apparently it is all very simple. However I get a compilation error, which I can not understand:

```
    /Users/alva/scala_prj/project/plugins.sbt:7: error: type mismatch;
     found   : Unit
     required: sbt.internals.DslEntry
    download(conf_plugin_uri, conf_plugin_file)
```

Maybe I am overlooking something fundamental here, for example some SBT configuration. Can anyone help me pointing me to the right documentation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** `sbt.IO.download(text_url, to_file)` returns `Unit` and since sbt parser doesn't accept it it ultimately leads to the error.

If you really insist on having the code inside `build.sbt`, you should instead define a new task and put the code to it.

```
import java.net.URL
import java.io.File

lazy val text_url = new URL("http://www.example.com/text.txt")
lazy val to_file = new File("text.txt")

lazy val download = taskKey[Unit](s"Saves $text_url to $to_file")
download := {
  sbt.IO.download(text_url, to_file)
}
```

See [Tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html).